# Unable to get Updated html in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a function in Javascript which is updating the textbox in the div to get updated html of div but it gives me blank value instead of updated one, Is anybody having idea why? Initialy the div is blank as below, and then I

```
<div id="editSeriesData">
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="400px">
        <tr>
            <td class="tableCell">
                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Series</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="" name="seriesid" id="seriesid" readonly /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td width="30%"><input type="text" name="seriesname" id="seriesname" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="description" id="description"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:validateFrm();" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And my Javascript method is:

```
function addEditSeries(seriesId){
    document.getElementById('seriesid').value=seriesId;
    document.getElementById('seriesname').value="dummy";
    document.getElementById('description').value="dummy";

    setTimeout(function(){      
        alert($('#editSeriesData').html());
        showwindow('','','280','500','Product-Pack Series',true, true,$('#editSeriesData').html());
    }, 1000);   
}
```

The alert() shows me whole div but without the updated value which I updated in addEditSeries() method. The value of the input fields remain as default.

Comment: have you tried `$("#seriesid").val(seriesId);` or `$("#seriesid").attr("value",seriesId);` ?

Comment: provide full html and javascript code as validateFrm() is missing in JS

Comment: @SantiagoHernández Thanks its works with  $("#seriesid").attr("value",seriesId);.